# SQL count not return all rows, phpmyadmin add LIMIT but not show it in the query

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, mysql-5.6

I have a query:

```
select lr2.event_id as ce
from data_requests as lr2 
group by lr2.event_id,
```

that returns 88 rows. Then I tried the following:

```
select count(lr2.event_id) as cc, lr2.event_id as ce 
from data_requests as lr2 
group by lr2.event_id
```

but it only returned 25 rows, so I am really puzzled, where did other 63 rows go.

I tried it in sqlfiddle, it seems to work correctly, but on my server it just doesn't, so it must be a setting or something... Feels like the server calculates the count after it select a subset of all group results. weird.

Comment: Which event_id are missing in the second query?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You will get *63 rows* in 2nd query only if there are **63 DISTINCT event_ids**

Comment: I guess you have the same value for `event_id` multiple times. The `group by` implies a distinct on the `event_id` column. If you change `count(event_id)` to `count(*)` you will see the number of duplicates for each `event_id`

Comment: even if I use count(*) it only return first 25 ids, is this a setting or something, but if I don't use count, then it return all results. weird

Comment: I am pretty sure the first query returns 88 rows indicate there are 88 distinct  event_id

Comment: Then please setup a http://sqlfiddle.com that shows this

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count the number of rows for each `lr2.event_id`you must use `count(*)` , not `count(lr2.event_id)` . Remember, you are counting rows.

Comment: Where is it stated that OP has a problem with the  number of rows for each `event_id`? He wants to know why both queries return a different row-count even if they use the same `GROUP BY`.

Comment: first query is like `select distinct lr2.event_id`, but second one is counting fields. When you use aggregate function such as count in a grouped query usually is for selecting all matching rows

Comment: if count(*) doesn't work too, I'm as puzzled as you are. The query is too simple. Try a `select distinct event_id from data_requests` to see how many rows returns

Answer (score 0):

**Function of GROUP BY**

> The SQL `GROUP BY` clause is used in collaboration with the `SELECT` statement to arrange identical/similar/equal data into groups.

**Demonstration**
If I have table like below, then 1st query will give same output as table definition:

```
ce
--
1
2
3
4
5
```

And 2nd query will give output as,

```
cc |ce
--- ---
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
```

Since, all are `distinct` in Table, I got 5 rows! but If some `ce` values are repetitive as,

```
ce
--
1
2
1
2
2
```

then, 2nd query will give output as:

```
cc |ce
--- ---
2   1
3   2
```

And here If I get shocked *where did other 3 rows go*? Then I need to study!
Of course, it's a spoon feeding! OP needs to study about [**GROUP BY**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it seems to be a phpmyadmin problem, I run the query in the phpmyadmin, and it auto added a limit in the end of every query

Comment: Mark your own answer as correct and change title so anybody with same problem can find your solution. And if you may add the results of the previous queries so it's clear you are not missing the criteria, better